# Monitor vs Notebook display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

When I connect my monitor via HDMI the letters are bigger than on my laptop screen. I tried to change something in `xrandr` but I am new to Ubuntu. Both my screens are 1920x1080 but I barely see the letters on my laptop screen. Any solution for this?

Here is my xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm 1920x1080     60.01*+  40.00  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
```

Comment: Well my notebook screen is 14" and the secondary monitor is 22"

Comment: well, I am pretty new to Ubuntu, just trying to learn it. Can you tell me please, which param should I change? I guess i have to do it via xrandr scaling.

Comment: It worked! Many thank to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to scale down the laptop display proportionately to make the letters on the laptop screen (173mm total usable height) the same height (in mm) as the external display (268mm total usable height), which works out to be increasing internal display sizing by a factor of 1.5. 1080/1.5 = 720 so make your internal screen 720 tall by 1280 wide to make the character sizes match